# form input value text truncated

Tags: php, mysql

The text that i try to show inside a form input is truncated when there is an apostrophe. Here is the code i use to insert data inside database (inside database the text is correctly inserted, see image below). I have this behavior only when there is an apostrophe. There is another image where you can see the output on the browser and indeed the output is weird..

```
$text = $_POST['text'];             // MEMORIZZO LA VARIABILE
$data = date("Y-m-d");              // PREPARO LA DATA
$id = '';                           // VARIABILE ID
$rows = array();                    // PREPARO ARRAY
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);     // INIZIALIZZO LA CONNESSIONE
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, 'INSERT INTO autovetture(name,data)
                        VALUES(?,?)') or die(mysqli_error($con));   // QUERY INSERIMENTO DATI
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss',$text,$data); // PREPARO I PARAMETRI
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);                         // ESEGUO LA QUERY
```

**This is the code i use to print the page:**

```
$html .= "<form  method='post'>";
$html .= "<div class='form-group'>";
$html .= "<label>Nome autovettura</label>";
$html .= "<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Inserisci il nome della Casa automobilistica' id='txt_auto_mod' value='{$rows1[name]}' />";
$html .= "</div>";
```

**Here you can see 3 grab:** 
one with the data inserted into database without error, one with the corrected ouput in the browser when there is no apostrophe and the last with the problem on the browser when there is the apostrophe. Here debugging the page with firebug you can see that the code is in someways misinterpreted ..

[image: grab 1]

[image: grab 2]

[image: grab 3]

Comment: Check the length of column you want to insert data? The length of column is 20 character only. So increase to whatever size is required

Comment: use `htmlentities` when trying to put value in form

Comment: the column type inside the database is a TEXT column and, in this case, the record is very short, just 18 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode the HTML entities when you are putting the value in form:

```
$html .= "<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Inserisci il nome della Casa automobilistica' id='txt_auto_mod' value='" . htmlentities($rows1[name], ENT_QUOTES) . "' />";
```

Comment: which method you tried? `htmlentities($rows1[name], ENT_QUOTES)`?

Comment: thanks it works! i used htmlentities($rows1[name], ENT_QUOTES)

Comment: welcome, please accept the answer and upvote if it is helpful.